# Integration of video calling functionality with Django and Django Channels

Tags: python, django, webrtc, django-channels, simplewebrtc

I have created a **chat application** with **Django** using **Django-Channels**, but for enhancement I want to add video calling functionality as well.

I'm not getting any Idea how i can achieve this task. Please provide me some references so that i can implement it.

Currently after searching the only option I'm getting is **WebRTC**.
But there is no proper documentation of integration with Django.

Comment: take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling

you should be able to use your websocket connection as the signaling server.